# How does this line of code work in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I got confused about this line of code, could anyone explain how this code work? I can understand that its using a pipeline, but codes in the middle confuses me.

```
for pid in $(ps -e -f | grep  $1 | grep -v $0 | awk '{print $2}')"
```

Comment: Is it just the `awk` part that you don’t understand, or something else? Might help you to look at the output at each stage: run `ps -e -f`, then `ps -e -f | grep [whatever $1 is]`, and so on.

Comment: You should probably use `pgrep` or `pkill` instead.

Comment: Minor grammar changes.  Changed awk to shell since it is a general shell question, not awk in particular.  Added tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check below details to understand the command, full command will be like this-

```
cat script.sh
for pid in $(ps -e -f | grep  $1 |grep -v $0 | awk '{print $2}')
do
kill -9 $pid
done
```

You need to execute it like below -

```
./script.sh vipin


step1 : ps -e -f (will print all the processes running in the server)
step2 : ps -e -f|grep $1 (considering $1 is variable for current user, 
        in my case is vipin(user) which i will pass with script,so step2
        will filter all the process for that user.

step3 : And $0 is the script name (script.sh), which you don't want to kill 
        that is why you are using grep -v(to exclude)
step4 : awk '{print $2}' to fetch only the process number.
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it.